# Single query categories and subcategories internal relationship

Tags: mysql

Having a design table like this one:

```
create table tbl_categories (
category_id int auto_increment,
parent_category_id int, -- internal foreign key
category_name varchar(255)
);
```

Let's add some records:

```
insert into tbl_categories (parent_category_id, category_name) values (null,'category 1'),(1, 'sub category 1'),(2, 'sub sub category 1'),(1, 'sub category 2'),(1, 'sub category 3');
```

How could I select to return as this:

```
category 1
category 1 >> sub category 1
category 1 >> sub category 1 >> sub sub category 1
category 1 >> sub category 2
category 1 >> sub category 3
```

just wondering if it there is any pattern to archive this on a single query.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code